# receipt printer on android pos device

Tags: android, printing, thermal-printer, point-of-sale

I have recently bought an android pos device P2000L with android 5.1.1 and tried to print on its built-in printer, but I ran into problem, I didn't know how to implement it.

RawBT didn't see the printer at all, I tried to send few ESCPOS command to it using adb shell to device tty, ttyHSL0, ttyHSL1 and even msm_thermal_query, none of them worked. I tried to find some documentations or SDK online but i found nothing.
I don't know to which interface it's connected and which protocol is used.

Does anybody have expirience with it or know how to solve it?

Thanks